# Validating forms using XAJAX

Tags: jquery, validation, form-submit, xajax

I am using jQuery to identify when a user has submitted the form. Then I call, using xajax, a php method to query the database and make sure that the usename and email address are not already in use.

```
  $('#newUserForm').submit(function() {
      var FormName = $(this).attr('name');
      xajax_validateEmailAddressAndUsername(xajax.getFormValues(FormName));
  });
```

Then in validateEmailAddressAndUsername I query the database and validate this way.
The problem that I have encounter is that jquery is asynchronous, and there is no way for me to add a script with the right xajax response before the form gets submitted. how can I address this problem? 
should I do it in a different way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have trouble with just using #(obj).submit().  .bind seems to be more reliable.
You could do something like this I think (untested):

```
$('#newUserForm').bind('submit', function() {
     var FormName = $(this).attr('name');
     if (xajax_validateEmailAddressAndUsername(xajax.getFormValues(FormName))) {
          $(this).submit();
     }
     else {
         alert("Oh no!"); 
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: this code gets stuck in an infinite recursion... 
But I think you are on to something. My question is: what should the xajax response be for the if statement to avaluate to TRUE?

Comment: I see why it gets stuck infinitely, I was in a rush when I wrote that response.  The if is currently returning true and resubmitting.  Try using $.post rather than $(this).submit()

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post